# Saving an EditText into an Array (different activity)

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-edittext

Thanks for taking the time of reading my post.

How would i be able to have the value of an email in an EditText (emailEditText) to be saved from Create.java into this array in the activity AlarmService?

Where it says `String[] toArr =`

Is there anyone that is able to provide a solution or give any suggestions? I have tried multiple times without success.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! :)

**AlarmService.java**

```
package com.example.pc.achieve;

import android.app.IntentService;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.PowerManager;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import static android.graphics.Color.GREEN;

public class AlarmService extends IntentService {

SharedPreferences pref;

PowerManager powerManager;
PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock;

public AlarmService() {
    super("");
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
    wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "FCFCFCFC");

    SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

    addNotification();
    sendMAIL();

}

public void addNotification() {
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon_transperent)
                    .setLights(GREEN, 700, 700)
                    .setContentTitle("Alert!")
                    .setContentText("This is a reminder");

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainMenu.class);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0,     notificationIntent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);

    // Add as notification
    NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    builder.setVibrate(new long[] { 0, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000 });
    manager.notify(0, builder.build());
}

public void sendMAIL(){

    String getEmail = pref.getString("email", "");
    String[] toArr = {getEmail};
    m.setTo(toArr);
    m.setFrom("notification@gmail.com");
    m.setSubject("Alert!");
    m.setBody("This is a reminder.");

    try {
        if(m.send()) {
        } else {
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}
}
```

**Create.java**

```
package com.example.pc.achieve;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class Create extends Activity {

SharedPreferences pref;

private EditText subjectEditText;
private EditText descEditText;
EditText emailEditText;

private DBManager dbManager;

    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_create);

        SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

        subjectEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.subject_edittext);
        descEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.description_edittext);
        emailEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email_edittext);
}

public void btnCreate(View view) {

    String email = emailEditText.getText().toString();
    pref.edit().putString("email", email).apply();

    dbManager = new DBManager(this);
    dbManager.open();

    final String name = subjectEditText.getText().toString();
    final String desc = descEditText.getText().toString();

    dbManager.insert(name, desc);

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setMessage("Your deadline has now been created.")
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    finish();
                }
            });
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
}


public void btnSetAlarm(View view) {

    startActivity(new Intent(Create.this, Alarm.class));
}
}
```

Comment: do you want to save String from different activity into same array?

Comment: Yes the String of an email address i want to be stored in this array, where at the moment {"useremail@outlook.com"} is.

Comment: put that array in `Bundle` and pass the same to activities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use SharedPreference to get string value in another activity:
In your EditText activity:

Declare globally:

```
SharedPreferences pref;
```

Initiate in onCreate() of both activity:

```
pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this); //Here is my change
```

Initialize `editText`s in `onCreate()`:

```
subjectEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.subject_edittext);
descEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.description_edittext);
emailEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email_edittext);
```

In `btnCreate()` method:

```
String email = emailEditText.getText().toString();
pref.edit().putString("email", email).apply();
```

In your String[] activity:

```
String getEmail = pref.getString("email", "");
String[] toArr = {getEmail};
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i do not have onCreate() in my second activity. I have updated my original post with extra information.

Comment: I am still having issues with the app crashing and saying shared preferences is trying to save null data.

Comment: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference

Comment: You always have to initilize views(editText, buttons etc.) in onCreate(). Otherwise you will get null pointer exception. Check my updated answer.

Comment: I followed your updated post but i am still getting this error. I have updated my original post with my code. java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick.  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'android.content.SharedPreferences$Editor android.content.SharedPreferences.edit()' on a null object reference

Comment: Original post has now been updated. Thanks for your help so far, i really appreciate it.

Comment: That has worked, i am now receiving email automatically to whatever email address is entered! Thank you so much for your time, i really appreciate it. I have marked reply as the working answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

Write it into shared preferences and on another activity check before if email is present load it from shared preferences.
http://androidopentutorials.com/android-sharedpreferences-tutorial-and-example/ 
here is nice and easy example to understand shared preferences.
If you want it on runtime you can also pass it via Intents. Study intents and shared preferences.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to store those String of email address in runtime and don't need them later so define public static String[] in MainActivity and then add value from different activities.
inside MainActivity (Or first Activity (my recommendation)) define it

```
public static String[] emails;
```

in another activity call it and add to its elements but to avoid overwrite do this

```
int count = MainActivity.emails.length;
MainActivity.emails = new String[count + 1];
MainActivity.emails[count + 1] = "newemail@mail.com";
```

but if you want to save it and use it later better to save in file.
hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks but i need the email to be saved for later use. I am still having problems getting this to work correctly.

Answer (score 1):

**Something like this**

```
String[] all_emails= new String[10]; // initialise array

String email= edutText.getText().toString(); // Get text from EditText
all_emails[index] = email;  //add to array like... all_emails[0] = email;
```